# Setting HTTPS headers with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, https, leaflet

I'm trying to include an authorisation token in a header using Leaflet and leaflet-wms-header (with leaflet-wms-header index.js included in my HTML) - without success. My code, based on the leaflet-wms-header README, is:

```
const OS_SERVICE_URL = 'https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/wmts';
currentToken = response.access_token;  // as received from token server
map = L.map('map', mapOptions);
markers = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
//  L.tileLayer(OS_SERVICE_URL + '?' + mapParamsString).addTo(map); // this works!
L.tileLayer.wmsHeader(
    OS_SERVICE_URL + '?' + mapParamsString,
    {
    layers: 'ne:ne',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    },
    [{ header: 'Authorization', value: 'Bearer ' + currentToken }],
    null).addTo(map);  // this doesn't work!
```

My browser console message is:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...L.tileLayer.wmsHeader...')
updateAPIToken — site.js:296
\\ remainder of trace omitted
```

Comment: Remove the `const OS_SERVICE_URL = ... ` in the `wmsHeader` options

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The spurious const OS_SERVICE_URL = ...  in the wmsHeader options text in the options was a miss-paste when creating the code snippet - it wasn't in the original code. (I've now corrected my code above.) So, I'm afraid my original problem still stands.